# How to discover/identify a code from a special character

Tags: regex, character-encoding, escaping, special-characters, non-ascii-characters

Maybe a really dumb question

How do I know the code from a special character. I'm trying to format a string like the image below

[image]

Although, when I copy the special characters all I got is blank spaces. I've tried different encodings (utf8, latin1, iso) to replace this character but none worked.

All I know is:

- The string is inserted into sql server from a GeNeXuS code
- The string is retrieved from sql server and written to a csv using spark
- ** A friend told me that this special character MAY BE shift + enter on GeNexuS

My main question is:

- How can I discover what type of character is this? Knowing what type is it I can use a replace or regex function to remove it from my spark DF.

Comment: To help us, you should not include picture, but actual characters. And if this site show you something interesting, it is just a font problem on your side, but probably we just get the "replacement character". Then you should give us the binary value (better in hexadecimal) of the offending characters. From there you can check Wikipedia (or we can answer and explain you the receipt, but now it would be too abstract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tries, my solution was remove all unidecode characters. My regex function is (in pyspark)

```
regexp_replace(col("NAME"), "[^a-zA-Z]", " ")
```

With this, I removed all unidecode characters and replace it by a blank space